# Who is the Compiler?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, vampire-the-requiem

In many of the *Vampire: the Requiem* sourcebooks, there are mentions of someone known as "the compiler".

Since I don't own every book, I wanted to know if you all might know more than me about this mysterious figure behind the curtain.

Is he a kindred, or something similar? Is there a sourcebook with more information on him?

In Night Horrors Immortal Sinners one of the storyhooks for the unholy mention him on page 141 and that he may use the initials V.T.
In the clanbook of the Ventrue both sample characters got mentioned as the "authors" of the book but that the compiler is giving them orders for the research.

Comment: Not an answer, but in a vampire game don't the initials V. T. *always* stand for [Vlad Tepes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vlad_the_Impaler)?

Comment: @HeyICanChan You'd think -- but that's a red herring this time. W.H. isn't Wilhelmina Harker either.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"V.T." is Vincent Temple, who's also featured in the **Daeva** clanbook. He's an investigator into the nature of elders in torpor, and he is the compiler—but only of the Ventrue clanbook. The rest of the story is woven through the five Requiem clanbooks, and though the story is obscured by the usual level of deception and subterfuge in White Wolf in-character fiction, it's likely that he and the other compilers are being manipulated by a greater power into collecting the information.